# While initializing RestHighLevel client do we always need to use new RestHighLevel client and new host?

Tags: elasticsearch

RestHighLevelClient client =
new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));

My question is do we always need to use new HttpHost ? Is there a way where we can maintain a pool of connections ?

We are having GET and POST apis and client.search() is always called when  there is a request triggered from front end.  So everytime a new request is triggered a new connection is created.  Is there a better approach of handling it. ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create multiple `RestHighLevelClient` in your application as mentioned in the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_changing_the_client_8217_s_initialization_code.html) `JHLRC` is a thread safe client and typically instantiated by the application at startup and can be used by all the requests in your application.

**from the same doc**

> The RestHighLevelClient is thread-safe. It is typically instantiated
> by the application at startup time or when the first request is
> executed.

Internally `JHLRC` maintains the pool of connection also does the load-balancing between Elasticsearch nodes, so you don't have to worry about these internals.